# Enabling search by super-key in Ubuntu Mate

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate

Can I somehow enable searching by super-key (windows logo), in Ubuntu MATE?
Like Ubuntu has that menu which shows up after clicking super-key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe **Synapse** launcher is included in Ubuntu MATE and might already be running in the background. You should be able to run it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>. If that doesn't work, you can launch it manually in the Accessories menu and then bring it up at anytime with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>.

Comment: Can I add shortcut to this command. I want it to be a win (super) key

Comment: I have no idea, sorry. You could look in the Synapse preferences to see if you can change the shortcut key, maybe?